# Subpixel rendering of 1px height div

Tags: css, html-rendering

Honestly,

I've battled this problem for a long time now and it's starting to annoy me. Sub-pixel rendering causes to many problems. For example if you have two images floated next to each other, in CSS these should be exactly next to each other however because of sub-pixel rendering there is a faint white line between each.

Or how about that div which is 1px high however however it renders across 2 pixels at half opacity.

I'm sick of things looking fuzzy because of things like flex centering to the absolute like 245.5 however if you get your browser to an even number everything looks sharp.

I was just wondering if there is a way of turning sub-pixel rendering for those who do not have retina (sub-pixel) screens? The simulated way (font-smoothing: antialiased) looks nice on text but awful on divs.

It's something I sometimes get around by using transform: translateY(0.5px); but it's not reliable as it isn't always guaranteed it will render sub-pixel.

So many times I've had clients ask about "white line between images" and having to do margin: -1px; inside a div with overflow hidden to correct it.

Anyway,
Is there something I'm missing here? Is there anything we can do to combat this?

Thanks

Comment: There is no answer. If CSS had anything like "round to whole pixels" that would be wonderful, but it doesn't.